# Python & Pandas: Structuring conditionals

Tags: python, pandas

Probably a rookie question, but I'm new to Python and Pandas and still learning the syntax. I'm developing a script where I'd like to structure a conditional that multiplies a cell value over an entire column.

Here's the structure of the `test.csv`:

[image]

I'd like to create a column `error_count_score` that multiplies the value in the `error_count` cell by 3 if it is greater than 3 (as an Excel formula, it would be: `=IF(C2<=3,0,(C2*3))` ). The values for the new column in this case would be `0` and `12`.

I suspect there are multiple ways to solve this, but I'm uncertain how to structure the code.
Here's my working code attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
    
df.loc[df['error_count'] >= 3, 'error_count_score'] = #do I put an object here? * 3
```

Any assistance or advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that does exactly what you want **for a single element in the column**, and then **apply** that function over every element of the column, generating your new column.

This is done via the `DataFrame.apply` method.

In your case:

```
def my_function(element):
    if element <= 3:
        return 0
    else: 
        return element * 3

df['error_count_score'] = df['error_count'].apply(my_function)
```

Note that pandas expects `my_function` to take an argument (each element of a column), and then *apply* it through some logic, returning a new element in the end. This is exactly what's happening here.

As you get used to pandas, you'll see that a lot of times people don't bother defining a function just to apply it a single time. In these cases, people will use an anonymous function - basically a function that only exists for one line - using the `lambda` keyword.

In your case:

```
df['error_count_score'] = df['error_count'].apply(lambda element: 0 if element <= 3 else element * 3)
```